# When does water intake for an infant start?

Tags: water

At what age can an infant start drinking water? I am aware that before a certain age, babies should not drink anything but milk because their stomachs are small and only can intake the nutrients it needs to grow. When does this end? and when can they start drinking sips of water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK, the NHS advice is to start offering sips of water, alongside a meal, from 6 months ([NHS drink and cups for young babies](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/baby/weaning-and-feeding/drinks-and-cups-for-babies-and-young-children/)). Solids should also be introduced around six months old. Continue to offer milk (breast or formula), baby will naturally reduce milk feeds when they start to eat more solids. A little water alongside solids is often helpful with the change in bowel habits following introduction of solids too.

From experience, don't expect baby to drink more than a sip of water with a meal. The cup mostly ends up elsewhere, with water on the high chair tray. Call it sensory play and congratulate yourself on being one of those cool parents with time for setting up sensory play for their kids!